# Bitwise Multiply by 5/8 Watching for Overflow

Tags: c

I have been assigned a whole host of problems and this is the only one I can't figure out how to optimize more.

The goal is to multiply by 5/8ths rounding toward 0 and preventing overflow. Order of operations is multiplying by 5 then dividing by eight (i.e. 11 * 5/8 = 6). The goal for optimization is to use 12 or less operators.

The stipulations are that only ! ~ & ^ | + << >> operations and 8 bit ints are allowed.

My current attempt at the solution is

```
int trueFiveEighths (int x){
    int rightOne = x >>1;
    int rightTwo = x >>2;
    int temp = (x &(rightTwo) &1) + (((x ^(rightTwo))|(rightOne)|x)&(x>>31)&1);
    return (x>>3) + (rightOne) + temp;
}
```

Which comes in at 14 operations. I don't see a way to shave any more operators off and I can't figure out another way.

Comment: Parentheses are an operator

Comment: I guess they are allowed as they haven't been counted by the checker.

Comment: @M.M: Apparently not for this purpose.

Comment: Preventing overflow means that shifting first may not be correct.  Of course shifting down for divide hurts precision.  So a trade off.

Comment: Sometimes it says operations, sometimes operators. Changed the question to say operations.

Comment: Can you confirm if you want rounding or truncating?  Rounding to 0 doesn't quite make sense.

Comment: The information snippet says rounding.

Comment: `((x << 2) + x) >> 3`  Algebra: (4x+x)/8 = 5x/8.  This is truncated. If you really want rounding, I'll let you work that out.

Comment: What do you mean by "8 bit ints"?

Comment: @M.M we are not allowed to straight up create an int to use large than 255 or 0xff. In example on of the problems was to return a 32 bit value with every even bit set to 0 (0x55555555). This value was constructed by doing val = (0x55+(0x55<<8)); and val += val<<16;

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can divide by eight:

```
int const eights = x >> 3;
```

get the remainder:

```
int const rem = x & 7;
```

multiply each by five:

```
eights += eights << 2;
rem += rem << 2;
```

and add any new wholes:

```
eights += rem >> 3;
```

combining:

```
int const eights = x >> 3;
int const rem = x & 7;

return eights + (eights << 2) + (rem + (rem << 2) >> 3);
```

for a total of eight of the counted operators.

To round negative numbers not divisible by eight towards zero, take advantage of sign extension (implementation-defined, so not portable, but probably the intended solution) to get the value 7 for a negative number and 0 for a positive one:

```
int const negative_mask = x >> 31 & 7;

return eights + (eights << 2) + (rem + (rem << 2) + negative_mask >> 3);
```

All together:

```
int const eights = x >> 3;
int const rem = x & 7;

return eights + (eights << 2) + (rem + (rem << 2) + (x >> 31 & 7) >> 3);
```

11 operators.

Comment: Like this better than mine - it handles overflow.

Comment: That is a good deal less. According to the checker it fails 0x80000001 by giving 0xb0000000 when it should be 0xb0000001. Its the rounding toward zero behavior that foils this and that confuses me because 0x80000000 should return 0xb000000 not 0xb000001. Working on that now.

Comment: @Falderol: Oh, this is supposed to work on signed integers? Whoops. Give me a bit… (or maybe you’ll get it!)

Comment: @Falderol `0x80000001` is out of range for a 32-bit `int`.  If you mean that it fails for negative numbers, then you are doomed since shifting negative numbers is undefined behaviour

Comment: @M.M: Left shift is defined if the result fits; right shift is implementation-defined, not undefined.

Comment: @Ryan left-shift is undefined (C11 6.5.7/4). You're right about right-shift being implementation-defined. I guess the answer would also have to specify a particular set of implementation definitions (including negative number representations)

Comment: @Falderol: Updated.

Comment: @M.M: Ah, sorry, you’re right. This is kind of an unfortunate assignment, then. Maybe some flavour of assembly would be better.

Comment: @Ryan its throwing another error now fo 0x7fffffff gives 0x50000000 when it should be 0x4fffffff.

Comment: @Falderol: Erm, `0x7fffffff` isn’t an 8-bit integer. Are you sure that’s the restriction? Could you include the exact wording in your question, please?

Comment: @Falderol: If you’re using 32-bit integers, replace `>> 7` with `>> 31`.

Comment: @ryan We are always passed 32 pit integers into the function but we can not declare integers larger than 32 bits. (i.e. writing int x = 0xffffffff is illegal but x = 0xff is fine)

Comment: @ryan I fell stupid for not spotting that but it works now. Thank you doe your help.

Comment: i didn't quite understand the rounding to zero part, like how does it work?

Comment: @PyWalker2797: `negative_mask` is 7 when the result is negative. If you have an existing operation x / 8 that rounds down for integers x < 0, (x + 7) / 8 rounds toward zero.

Comment: But why don't we do it when we compute `int const eights = x >> 3;`

Comment: @PyWalker2797: `eights` gets multiplied by 5. We want + 1, not + 5. If you mean something else, try it, maybe it works.

Answer (score 1):

Here, we multiply by 4, then add X to get to 5, then add 1/2 X for rounding.
Then, divide by 8 (shift 3).

```
return ((x << 2) + (x) + (x >> 1)) >> 3;
```

If truncating towards 0,

```
return ((x << 2) + (x)) >> 3;
```

This by itself will not protect against an overflow because we do the multiply by 5 first.  We could shift down first, but then we lose precision.  Mixing the multiplies up with down shifts could very well give you a middle ground between precision and overflow protection.

The above method does have the advantage of using very few operations and is code I have used in the way back machine on systems that did not have a multiplier built in (Gameboy/GBC)